# Adding HTML attributes to a multi-line section of markdown

Tags: markdown

I would like to have a special CSS be invoked for H4 and H3 and P over a series of lines in Markdown. I'm using Kramdown but I would be willing to use another one if it has the needed feature. I tried this:

```
<div id="X">

### Header

#### Header2

blah 

</id>
```

And it didn't work. The headers were not interpreted as markdown. I also tried it with `<span>`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You don't state which Markdown implementation you are using. The original [rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) don't allow Markdown processing inside block level raw HTML However, many implementations either allow it under certain situations or provide a setting to change the behavior. Some implementations also provide a non-standard mechanism for defining IDs (either auto generated or manually) for individual headers. But we need to know which implementation you are using to point out which options are available to you (if any).

Comment: Kramdown, but willing to change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kramdown gives you many options, which are explained in turn below.

As the Markdown [rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) explain:

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within
>   block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style `*emphasis*`
>   inside an HTML block.

## Use raw HTML

Of course, you can always use all raw HTML, which will work across all implementations. In fact, if you look at the [source](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax.text) for the original Markdown rules, you can see that all of the headers are defined using raw HTML so that IDs can be assigned to each. Therefore, this should do the trick:

```
<h3 id="foo">Header</h3>
<h4 id="bar">Header2</h4>
<p class="baz">blah</p>
```

Of course, then you loose the benefits of writing (and reading) in Markdown. However, Kramdown provides many options to work around that.

## parse_block_html

Kramdown provides the [parse_block_html](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html#option-parse-block-html) option which, when enabled allows Markdown processing within raw HTML blocks. However, the documentation for that option notes:

> Since this is not wanted normally, the default is `false`. It is
>   normally better to selectively enable kramdown processing via the
>   markdown attribute.

## markdown=1

The mention of "the markdown attribute" above is referring to a non-standard add-on to the Markdown syntax which Kramdown supports by default and documents in the [HTML Blocks](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks) section of its documentation:

> It is also possible to enable/disable syntax parsing on a tag per tag
>   basis using the markdown attribute:
>
> - If an HTML tag has an attribute `markdown="0"`, then the tag is parsed as raw HTML block.
> - If an HTML tag has an attribute `markdown="1"`, then the default mechanism for parsing syntax in this tag is used.
> - If an HTML tag has an attribute `markdown="block"`, then the content of the tag is parsed as block level elements.
> - If an HTML tag has an attribute `markdown="span"`, then the content of the tag is parsed as span level elements.

In your case, using `markdown="1"` should do the trick (although `block` should work as well).

```
<div id="X" markdown="1">

### Header

#### Header2

blah 

</div>
```

## Attribute List Definitions

However, you don't need to fall back to raw HTML as Kramdown allows you to [define IDs](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#specifying-a-header-id) directly on headers and other elements using [Attribute List Definitions](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#attribute-list-definitions).

```
### Header  {#foo)

#### Header2 {#bar}

blah
{: .baz}
```

The above Markdown would be converted to the following HTML:

```html
<h3 id="foo">Header</h3>
<h4 id="bar">Header2</h4>
<p class="baz">blah</p>
```

## auto_ids

Finally, Kramdown also includes support for an [auto_ids](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html#option-auto-ids) option which, when enabled, adds auto-generated IDs to every header.

Comment: Wow, great info. I thought I'd seen all the kramdown options. Just what I wanted!

Comment: It's probably </div>, not </id>? (Cannot suggest an edit as stackoverflow says it's too short)